# Can Jenkins reuse docker layer cache between nodes/slaves

Tags: jenkins

Does jenkins have similar feature like CircleCI DLC (docker layer cache) that allows us to mount docker layer cache so that it can reused in different nodes.

[https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/docker-layer-caching/#:~:text=Learn%20More-,Overview,used%20to%20run%20your%20job](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/docker-layer-caching/#:%7E:text=Learn%20More-,Overview,used%20to%20run%20your%20job)

Comment: I had a similar question for GitHub Actions. My local runners keep running out of disk and docker is usually the reason. Sharing a cache between runners would seem like an obvious solution e.g. by mounting the cache on a large nfs drive. The option seems to be there i.e. https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-move-docker-s-default-var-lib-docker-to-another-directory-on-ubuntu-debian-linux but I am not sure what happens when multiple docker instances are trying to access the same layers on an nfs share. I'm going to just try some stuff and see how it works. If I remember I might put an answer in here